# Asignar ImagenView en el codigo java

Tags: android

Tengo un ImagenView y le asigno una imagen en el archivo XML, como puedo asignar a ese mismo ImagenView otras imagenes desde MainActivity.java, las debo agregar a la carpeta drawable?, como las manipulo desde el còdigo java.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Si la tienes dentro de la carpeta Drawable puedes usar esto:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagenPropia);
```